# AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'ids'. Why this happens?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner, picking up the code piece by piece. I just don't have time to learn Kivy library, so I try my best to write functionality of my program. The man gave me my correct code, but I honestly don't understand why it gives me an error and how to fix it. Help me please <3

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    id: bl
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: [5] 
    spacing: 10
"""

class MyButton(Button):
    color=(0, 0, 0, 1)
    valign='bottom'
    padding_y=10
    background_color=(.93, .91, .67, 1)
    background_normal=''
 
class MyApp(App):
  
    def build(self):

        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self)
        
        self.ids.bl.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети»', on_press=self.btn_press))

    def btn_press(self,instance):
        self.ids.bl.clear_widgets()
        sc = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None))
        x = 1
        data = ''
        while True:
            if x == 1:
                url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=1"
            elif x < 57:
                url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=" + f'{x}'
            else:
                break
            request = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
            teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
            for temes in teme:
                data += temes.text
            x = x + 1
        sc.add_widget(Label(text=f'{data}'))
        self.ids.bl.add_widget(sc)
```

Comment: you use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` without importing it

Comment: `self.ids` is never defined.  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: and maybe add the errors you get to your question

Comment: @Gandhi sorry i miss two imports. But if they are, errors are:
line 949, in _run_prepare
     self.dispatch('on_start')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch


self.ids.bl.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети»', on_press=self.btn_press))
 AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'ids'

Comment: Try changing `self.ids.bl` to `self.root.ids.bl`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson

  self.root.ids.bl.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. «Отцы и дети»', on_press=self.btn_press))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops. Sorry, my mistake. The problem is that you cannot assign an `id` to the root widget in a `kv` rule. So the correct fix for your code is to replace:

```
self.ids.bl.add_widget
```

with just:

```
self.root.add_widget
```